# Passing list value to loadworkbook || Python

Tags: python

I have a list named tickets

```
tickets = ['ITSVC-YY160044392', 'ITSVC-YY170045022', 'ITSVC-YY170045032']
```

I have excel attachments for same list tickets like

ITSVC-YY160044392.xlsx,ITSVC-YY170045022.xlsx,ITSVC-YY170045032.xlsx

for the items in `tickets[]`  i had to open their respective excel files

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import openpyxl as xl
for x in cdc_tickets():
     wb = xl.load_workbook('x.xlsx')
     b = wb.active
```

In the statement  `wb = xl.load_workbook('x.xlsx')` in place of 'x' i want my list values that are stored in tickets to be passed to load the respective excel like

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('ITSVC-YY160044392.xlsx')
```

How to pass list value to loadwork statement?

Comment: You're asking how to add the string `".xlsx"` to your `x` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of string formatting. You can find some easy examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples).

```
filename = "{}.xslx".format(x)
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
```